# Is there any use to creating an interface that would only be implemented once?

Tags: php, interface

I'm going through this tutorial I found, for building a router in PHP: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241

In it, the tutor creates a `Request` class, that implements an interface `IRequest`.

```
interface IRequest
{
    public function getBody();
}
```

This interface is implemented only by the `Request` class.

I understand that this is only a tutorial, but it leaves me a little confused as to why someone might do this. In this context, even if building upon this code to create a functional application, I can only imagine that this would only ever be implemented by the one `Request` class. Are there other types of requests (besides a HTTP request) that might conceivably use this interface?

Is there some other reason in general that you might create and use such a seemingly trivial interface? Perhaps I'm misguided in thinking that the main purpose of interfaces is to create uniformity in how you interact with them?

Hope I've conveyed my confusion well enough!

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it

Comment: @user3532758 Thanks! It seems like the key takeaways are that 1. the effort is minimal compared to how much effort it would otherwise take if you find out down the line that you do need one, 2. it helps in unit testing, and 3. it encourages more thoughtful design (e.g. you think more carefully about how different components or subsystems _should_ be interacting).